# Can't find variable: firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

There is 'Can't find variable: firebase' error and I can't find what causes the error. I have added firebase using '*yarn add firebase*' and confirmed several times if it is installed. I am using Nuxt.js and there is my firebase.js file below.

plugins/firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(
       {
          apiKey: "the keys",
          authDomain: "",
          projectId: "",
          storageBucket: "",
          messagingSenderId: "",
          appId: "",
          measurementId: ""
       }
    )
}

export default firebase
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever instructions you're following to integrate Firebase are incorrect for modern versions of the Firebase SDK.  You should follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize), and you'll see that you're supposed to import like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could successfully remove the error but getting 'Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).' error now. I added imports for firestore and auth but changed nothing else. Do you know any ways to solve this error?

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately.